How to stop program installer running every time I login?
Everytime I login, my computer wants to try to install an old version of "shipstation connect". If I say "don't install", it still pops up next time I login. How do I track down what is causing it and removing that installer from my computer?


https://help.shipstation.com/hc/en-us/articles/6289189879963-Upgrade-to-the-New-ShipStation-Connect

No that article doesn't help. Been through it with shipstation support and am getting no where.

What steps were tried and with what results? Make sure to [edit] the question to update it.

Take a look with Microsoft (Sysinternals) Autoruns. This application lists all the processes that start by themselves, such as these:

Windows Services,
Links in C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup,
Registry keys, e.g., HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run.



Search for ShipStation or Connect in the Quick Filter box.
Look in theEverything tab, or Logon, in particular.
Uncheck a box to deactivate a startup process, or delete that line completely, if you're sure it's safe to do so.

